# Finding the Geodesic Curvatures of a Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves, curvature

I have a question that I'm working on, and I have solved the question on my own terms, however I don't understand the solution that was provided, and would like to understand it. The question reads:

> Let $T$ be a Torus parametrized by:
>   $$\phi(\theta, \varphi) = ((R+r\cos(\theta))\cos(\varphi), (R+r\cos(\theta))\sin(\varphi), r\sin(\theta))$$
>   Find the Geodesic Curvature when $\theta=\text{constant}$ and $\varphi=\text{constant}$.

Now, the solution reads:
$$\phi_{\theta} = (-r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi), -r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi), r\cos(\theta))$$
$$\phi_{\varphi} = (-(R+r\cos(\theta))\sin(\varphi), (R+r\cos(\theta))\cos(\varphi), 0)$$
$$\vec N =(-\cos(\theta)\cos(\varphi), \cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi), \sin(\theta))$$
We have circles that have Radius $(R+r\cos(c))$ when $\theta=c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, the Curves when $\theta=c$ have curvature $\kappa_C = (R+r\cos(c))^{-1}$.

Projecting the Normal Vector of the Curve onto the Tangent Plane gives that the Geodesic Curvature is given by:
$$\kappa_G=\sin(c)\cdot(R+r\cos(c))^{-1}$$

I am wondering, what Tangent Plane is he talking about? Furthermore, how did he just know that projecting the Normal Vector of the Curve onto the Tangent Plane would be $\sin(c)$ times the Curve Curvature? If anyone had any tips to add to this I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You mean to find the *geodesic curvature* of the curves $\theta=\text{constant}$ and $\phi=\text{constant}$? The curves $\phi=\text{constant}$ are geodesics, so have geodesic curvature. With regard to your other question, look at definitions. The geodesic curvature comes from the part of the vector $\kappa n$ ($n$ principal normal) lying in the tangent plane of the surface. You need to draw some pictures and use some basic right-angle trigonometry.

Comment: yes, I have edited it accordingly

Comment: I'm confused because along $\theta=\textbf{constant}$, the Normal vector of this curve is always perpendicular to the Tangent Plane on this curve no?

Comment: No, that's for $\phi=\text{constant}$ (the little circles), isn't it?

Comment: I'm confused by the definition of the Tangent Plane for the Surface, theres not just one tangent plane on the entire surface, so how can he just generalize it as such?

Comment: Tangent plane of the surface at the point $P$ where you're computing geodesic curvature of the relevant curve!!!

Comment: Yes but wouldn't the Normal Vector of that Curve be perpendicular to the tangent plane at $P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a point $p$ of your torus, the normal field to a curve *in the sense of the Frenet frame* (green, scaled for visibility) need not be perpendicular to the tangent plane of the torus, and so can have a non-zero tangential component (blue), whose magnitude at $\phi(c, \varphi)$ is $\sin c$ times the magnitude of the normal vector.

[image: Geodesic curvature of a latitude on a torus]

Comment: How do you know that it's $\sin(c)$ times the magnitude of the normal vector? I'm confused by how to go about this question

Comment: The parameter $\theta$ is "latitude": $\theta = 0$ on the "outer equator", $\theta = \pi$ on the "inner equator", $\theta = \pi/2$ on the top circle, and so forth. In the plane, draw the unit circle with $\theta$ as polar coordinate (thinking of this circle as the translated meridian $\varphi = 0$), and consider the (green) vector $(-1, 0)$ and its (blue) projection to the tangent line to the circle. The length of the blue projection is $|\sin\theta|$ times the magnitude of the green vector by elementary trigonometry. :)